# Using LocationListener (with google play service) as service its getting too much false Location

Tags: android

I'm using Google Play Services to get location.

When I set the Location mode to High Accuracy then the map shows the blue dot as wrong but its showing the correct address. and my location manager also getting false location. How can i avoid the false location getting from Location manager?

Query : Is it possible to get location only use GPS by google play service, and omit the location update from WiFi.

![My location is the read marker and current location from Google play service is the blue icon]

[image]